# Wordpress - shortcode в <select> не работает

Tags: wordpress

Создал форму с селектом

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select class="form-control" name="formx" onchange="location = this.value;">
<option value="http:/site.com/category#info">Информация</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Все работает.

Создал shortcode в функции

```
function url_shortcode() {
return get_bloginfo('url');
}
add_shortcode('web_url','url_shortcode');
```

Шорткод [web_url] работает на страницах и постах, но он не работает в форме ! а именно такой

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select class="form-control" name="formx" onchange="location = this.value;">
<option value="[web_url]/category#info">Информация</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Открываю сурс а там в value стоит [web_url], т.е шорт код не выполняется.

В чем причина ? так как мне нужно использовать шорт код в формах, селектах.

Comment: А где размещена эта форма? В файле php или в тексте страницы, созданном в админке?

Comment: В Админке, если бы в php файле вопросов бы не возникало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress с версии 4.2 запрещает использование шорткодов в тегах html. Когда контент поста обрабатывается, запускается функция `do_shortcode(контент_поста)` в файле ядра `wp-includes/shortcodes.php`. Она вызывает `do_shortcodes_in_html_tags()`, которая заменяет все квадратные скобки в элементах html на html-сущности с помощью такого преобразования:

```
$trans = array( '[' => '&#91;', ']' => '&#93;' );
```

Это делается для того, чтобы квадратные скобки, которые допустимы внутри html по синтаксису, не ломали распознавание шорткодов в контенте поста. После этого производится обработка шорткода (вставка результата, возвращаемого пользовательской функцией, указанной в add_shortcode) и обратное преобразование html-сущностей в квадратные скобки.

Таким образом, ни в каком месте html-тега (и любого текста, начинающегося с отрывающей скобки < ) вставить шорткод не получается - я пробовал.

Единственным исключением является action="". Не знаю, ошибка это или так задумано (нужен более глубокий анализ кода ядра), но по факту `<form action="[web_url]>"` работает, а `<form action1="[web_url]">` - уже нет.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за развернутый ответ. Попробуем сделать по другому.

Answer (score 0):

Логично, что шорт-код выполняется в контенте при его обработке, однако он не будет выполняться в других местах, в т.ч. в шаблонах WordPress, которые по сути являются обыкновенными PHP-скриптами. Воспользуйтесь специальной функцией **do_shortcode** для обработки шорт-кода.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: Я думаю не логично, потому что я выполняю не php код прямо из страницы (создать страницу), а вывожу уже готовый результат обработки шорт кода, в ней. Шорт кода а именно [web_url] работает везде ! кроме ! тега <select> а именно в value тега <options> он не обрабатывается, почему мне не известно, впихнул его в action="" заработал, а в option value="" не работет.

Comment: вобщем сделал так <options value="/category#info">Info</options> заработало, но почему шорт код не работает в некоторых тегах для меня остаеться загадкой.